# How to call static block in magento and how to reorder them?

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

Can anyone tell me how to call static block in right side in Magento through XML and how to put them in order ? or how to reorder these blocks.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: it's urgent can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 2):

you can set in you `XML` or in `local.xml` like below

```
<layout>
     <default>
          <reference name="right">
          <block type="cms/block" name="right-page-block">
             <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>right-page-block</block_id></action>
          </block>
         </reference>
      </default>
</layout>
```

`before:` Used to position the block before a block with the name specified in the value. If "-" value used the block is positioned before all other blocks of its level of block nesting.

`after`: Used to position the block after a block with the name specified in the value. If "-" value used the block is positioned after all other blocks of its level of block nesting.

Updated: examples from some random core layout updates:

```
<reference name="right">
    <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" before="cart_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

above is template file block you can set instead of this your own static block

let me know if i can help you more.

Comment: Hello,
Thank for support, but i found that there is not local.xml is available.

Comment: you can add in your themes layout or if you want to add it in your other xml like page.xml you can also add it.